# How to loop through pixels array within selected area

Tags: image-processing, processing, nested-loops, pixel

How do I loop through each and every pixel within a selected area using 1D array?

For example:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+
|00|01|02|03|04|
+--+--+--+--+--+
|05|06|07|08|09|
+--+--+--+--+--+
|10|11|12|13|14|
+--+--+--+--+--+
|15|16|17|18|19|
+--+--+--+--+--+
|20|21|22|23|24|
+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Let's say the user selected the pixels 07, 08, 12 and 13 of the image and I want the program to loop through the selected pixels. How do I write the nested loop in order
get the loop to loop through just that 4 pixels?

Comment: Is this really a question for the Processing language or is that a wrong tag?

Comment: its for Processing language.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert from a loop index into 2d coordinates? (Or vice versa?)

Comment: pixels on coordinates `(x, y)` would be at `pixels[y*width+x]`

Answer (score 1):

You could build an array of pixels and then loop over this array instead.

Random programming language for today: Javascript

```
var pixelList = { 7,8,12,13 };
for (i=0; i<pixelList.length; i++)
{
    do_something_with_pixel (pixelList[i]);
}
```